# Is there a python library to determine the position of a satellite at a given time from TLE data excluding the Satellite catalog number?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, two-line-elements, python, orbit-determination

Or perhaps some simple code or formula that achieves this. I've used pyephem but it requires a Satellite catalog number.

Comment: Does pyephem require that the satellite catalog numbers you give it in the TLE data belong to an existing satellite?

Comment: How do you acquire the TLE data?  If you have a TLE on hand, it has the number right there on both lines.

Comment: Perhaps I should have elaborated a bit. I'm trying to calculate where an artificial satellite is in term of LAT/LON/ALT given just the orbital information contained in the TLE data. We'll just say that I'm dealing with a world where the satellites don't have catalog numbers. If there is a python package that does this that would be great. It actually doesn't have to be that accurate. My use-case tolerates an error of about +/- 2 degrees LAT/LON. If  such a library does not exist a simple algorithm should suffice.